# How to create a singleton that I can update in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, struct, singleton

I want to create a global variable for showing a loadingView. I tried lots of different ways but could not figure out how to. I need to be able to access this variable across the entire application and update the MotherView file when I change the boolean for the singleton.

```
struct MotherView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
        
    var body: some View {
        
        if isLoading { //isLoading needs to be on a singleton instance
            Loading()
        }

        
        switch viewRouter.currentPage {
        case .page1:
            ContentView()
        case .page2:
            PostList()
        }
    }
}

struct MotherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MotherView(viewRouter: ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

I have tried the below singleton but it does not let me update the shared instance? How do I update a singleton instance?

```
struct LoadingSingleton {
    static let shared = LoadingSingleton()
    var isLoading = false

    private init() { }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make your singleton a `ObservableObject` with `@Published` properties:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var loading = LoadingSingleton.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        if loading.isLoading {
            Text("Loading...")
        }
        ChildView()
        Button(action: { loading.isLoading.toggle() }) {
            Text("Toggle loading")
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView : View {
    @StateObject var loading = LoadingSingleton.shared

    var body: some View {
        if loading.isLoading {
            Text("Child is loading")
        }
    }
}

class LoadingSingleton : ObservableObject {
    static let shared = LoadingSingleton()
    @Published var isLoading = false
    
    private init() { }
}
```

I should mention that in SwiftUI, it's common to use `.environmentObject` to pass a dependency through the view hierarchy rather than using a singleton -- it might be worth looking into.

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass needing to use @ StateObject and @ ObservedObject? That was my goal with the singleton route. @jnpdx

Comment: Not really... I mean, you could try to make a `Combine` version all with Publishers, but it seems like an uphill battle and you'll end up having to add a ton of boilerplate code to every view. `@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` are property wrappers that help tell SwiftUI to update the view when something changes. Otherwise, the `View` doesn't know to update. Is there a reason that you're trying to avoid using them?

Comment: @jnpdx how to use . environmentObject in the above context? Im updating isLoading variable in some ViewModel and trying to use it in another swiftUI file. But the values dont update

Comment: @Honey hard to say what's going wrong without seeing a [mre] in a question

Comment: @jnpdx here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69628795/environmentobject-property-not-working-properly-in-swiftui/69629171?noredirect=1#comment123088101_69629171 . Plz suggest

Comment: Neat and simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

First, make `LoadingSingleton` a class that adheres to the `ObservableObject` protocol. Use the `@Published` property wrapper on `isLoading` so that your SwiftUI views update when it's changed.

```
class LoadingSingleton: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading = false
}
```

Then, put `LoadingSingleton` in your `SceneDelegate` and hook it into your SwiftUI views via `environmentObject()`:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    static let singleton = LoadingSingleton()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = ContentView()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(SceneDelegate.singleton))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}
```

To enable your SwiftUI views to update when changing `isLoading`, declare a variable in the view's struct, like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var singleton: LoadingSingleton

    var body: some View {
        //Do something with singleton.isLoading
    }
}
```

When you want to change the value of `isLoading`, just access it via `SceneDelegate.singleton.isLoading`, or, inside a SwiftUI view, via `singleton.isLoading`.